# Not able to Launch Edge with Remote Driver can some one pls help

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, browser-automation, testcase, remote-webdriver

```
DesiredCapabilities capabillities = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
            capabillities.setBrowserName(BrowserType.EDGE); 
      
    capabillities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);     
    capabillities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
        capabillities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT , true);
        capabillities.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);  
        capabillities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_VERSION, "latest");
        
        WebDriver driver = null;
        List<String> displayedList = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        
        try {
            System.out.println("STARTED");
            
            
            
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("url"), capabillities);
            driver.get("https://url"); 
            
            System.out.println("OPENED");
```

I am getting the below  Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create session from {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "acceptSslCerts": true,
    "browserVersion": "latest",
    "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
    "javascriptEnabled": true,
    "ignoreProtectedModeSettings": true,
    "version": "",
    "platform": "WIN10"
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "firstMatch": [
      {
        "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
        "browserVersion": "latest",
        "platformName": "win10"
      }
    ]
  }
}
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:22:52'
System info: host: 'VDI-PR-E0042', ip: '10.93.173.183', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 1.35 seconds
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:143)
    at Test.TestRemoteGrid.main(TestRemoteGrid.java:60)
```

Comment: If you need our help, you need to provide all information like error messages, "Not able to Launch Edge" can mean many different things.

Comment: have added if you could give inputs will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in C# before (code below is C#) but it looks to be just about the same in [Java](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/edge/EdgeDriver.html).

```
// Create an options object to specify command line arguments for the Edge web driver
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
// Use Remote Edge
try
{
    // Create a remote session using the Grid Hub URI (from the App.config)
    returnValue = new RemoteWebDriver(hubUri, options);
}
// Use Local Edge
catch
{
    // Write result to log
    Log.WriteLine("    [WARNING] Unable to create a remote session, so creating a local one.");
    // Create a local session
    returnValue = new EdgeDriver(options);
}
```